# How can I capture ethernet frames in Android?

Tags: android, networking

I can only capture network layer packet when using VpnService, how can I capture ethernet frames?

Or how can I know the protocol of a network layer packet?

Comment: I don't think something like that is possible without root.

Comment: @meeeee actually I want to know the protocol of the packet. Do you know some other ways to find out the protocol if I can't get ethernet frame?

Comment: I wouldn't know how. However a Playstore search finds apps that have packet sniffing / capturing without root, so it seems to be possible.

Comment: Not all layer-2 protocols are ethernet. It is likely that using Android, you will have Wi-Fi and 4G frames, which are different than ethernet frames. At which layer are you looking for the protocol? At layer-3, you can probably only have IPv4 or IPv6.

Comment: @Ron Maupin There are also other protocols like icmp, but I don't how to distinguish them.

Comment: That depends on the layer which you are examining. With ethernet, there is the EtherType field in the layer-2 frame header that tells you which layer-3 protocol is encapsulated in the payload of the frame. The IP protocols have something similar at layer-3: IPv4 has the Protocol field, and IPv6 has the Next Header field that tells you which layer-4 protocol is encapsulated in the layer-3 frame.